# Start tmux pane with prompt at the bottom

Tags: command-line, tmux

Is it possible to get tmux to start all of its panes with the prompt at the bottom, instead of at the top? After a pane has been in use for a while the output means that the prompt is at the bottom, so it just seems to make sense to have the prompt always at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Add this you your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-command 'tput cup "$(tput lines)"; exec "$SHELL" -l'
```

This will run `tput cup "$(tput lines)"` (taken from [your own answer](https://superuser.com/a/1546467/432690)) before spawning a shell in a new pane. It should work regardless of what shell you use.

Notes:

- The default `default-command` is not always equivalent to `"$SHELL" -l` (see `man 1 tmux`). If you're using the `default-shell` option then you should use the full path of the executable instead of `$SHELL`. This is very important if your `$SHELL` is `tmux` itself.
- If you specify a command explicitly (e.g. `bash` in `tmux split-window bash`) then it will start from the top because `default-command` doesn't matter in such case.
- Instead of `tput cup "$(tput lines)"` you can inject newline characters with `yes "" | head -n 100`. An advantage of this approach is if the height of the pane increases just after (e.g. you destroy adjacent pane(s)) then these 100 newlines will most likely be enough to keep the prompt at the bottom. A disadvantage is they will appear in the pane's history.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, using [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153102/how-to-start-xterm-with-prompt-at-the-bottom) as inspiration. I added this line to the end of my *.bashrc*:

```
tput cup "$LINES"
```

Or for those poor machines where I need to use csh, this in my .cshrc:

```
tput cup `tput lines`
```

It seems to work fine, but obviously it's not tmux specific.